# How to exit pew venv

Tags: python-venv

I'm using [Python env Wrapper](https://github.com/berdario/pew) and was wondering how to deactivate/exit from the environment without having to close my shell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to type in `exit` in your terminal rather than the traditional `deactivate` for a venv.